# NSSplitView left view flexible and right view fixed when resizing

Tags: cocoa, nssplitview

I'm creating a vertical `NSSplitView` programmatically.

I want the right view to start at a specified width.  Then if the window is resized I want the right view to stay at that exact width unless changed by the user.

Right now when you resize an `NSSplitView` both views change size proportionally.  I'm using auto layout so I can't use the delegate methods in `NSSplitViewDelegate` such as `-splitView:shouldAdjustSizeOfSubview:`.

I'm confused how I would implement this behavior in auto layout for a split view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the holdingPosition of each view. 
You can adjust them temporarily for certain changes.

Session 213 from WWDC 2013 videos covers this well.